# Inconsistent columns width issue in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've created a column chart width 2 series data with 61 entries in each series.
By default the columns width should be similar but it is getting inconsistent.

`Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ["May 12", "Jun 12", "Jul 12", "Aug 12", "Sep 12", "Oct 12", "Nov 12", "Dec 12", "Jan 13", "Feb 13", "Mar 13", "Apr 13", "May 13", "Jun 13", "Jul 13", "Aug 13", "Sep 13", "Oct 13", "Nov 13", "Dec 13", "Jan 14", "Feb 14", "Mar 14", "Apr 14", "May 14", "Jun 14", "Jul 14", "Aug 14", "Sep 14", "Oct 14", "Nov 14", "Dec 14", "Jan 15", "Feb 15", "Mar 15", "Apr 15", "May 15", "Jun 15", "Jul 15", "Aug 15", "Sep 15", "Oct 15", "Nov 15", "Dec 15", "Jan 16", "Feb 16", "Mar 16", "Apr 16", "May 16", "Jun 16", "Jul 16", "Aug 16", "Sep 16", "Oct 16", "Nov 16", "Dec 16", "Jan 17", "Feb 17", "Mar 17", "Apr 17", "May 17"],
        crosshair: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      column: {
        pointPadding: 0,
        borderWidth: 0,
        groupPadding: 0.08
      }
    }, 
    series: [{"name":"series1","data":[265,244,226,268,259,306,329,378,291,344,263,356,385,228,202,262,331,272,315,249,181,277,292,396,234,181,185,210,202,189,197,233,270,351,378,222,384,450,304,182,180,236,540,173,135,142,207,267,206,261,249,247,161,253,239,221,143,144,187,197,109],"color":"#1f497d"},{"name":"series2","data":[199,203,146,161,134,143,155,184,168,183,149,187,168,162,218,192,144,153,164,150,140,174,195,151,148,112,149,163,141,142,151,163,147,132,240,191,180,159,139,132,157,171,166,185,130,141,304,173,151,134,127,172,147,134,142,161,127,113,150,147,57],"color":"#8eb4e3"}]
});`.

http://jsfiddle.net/ynkq44oj/

Comment: With that amount of data I would suggest a different type of chart to visualize them. How about a line chart (https://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-labels) or a HighStock data group (https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/data-grouping).

Answer (score 1):

Set [series.crisp](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.crisp) to false.

> **crisp: Boolean**
>
> When true, each column edge is rounded to its nearest pixel in order
>   to render sharp on screen. In some cases, when there are a lot of
>   densely packed columns, this leads to visible difference in column
>   widths or distance between columns. In these cases, setting crisp to
>   false may look better, even though each column is rendered blurry.
>   Defaults to true.
>
> *http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.crisp*

```
plotOptions: {
  column: {
   pointPadding: 0,
   borderWidth: 0,
   groupPadding: 0.08,
   crisp: false
  }
},
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/ynkq44oj/4/

Comment: I had tried with this option already but the problem is the chart looks hazy., the spaces between columns also not clear, it looks like columns are overlapping each other.

Comment: You can try to experiment with pointWidth property - and set it dynamically depending on the number of columns and hte chart's width

Answer (score 0):

Using 
`crisp: false` option solved the issue. But in some cases the chart looks hazy.

http://jsfiddle.net/ynkq44oj/1/